# jquery select all br with display:none;

Tags: jquery

How do I select an element based on its css?

I need to select a br with inline style display:none. This is not the same thing as br:hidden, because that selects elements that are hidden in other ways, and I don't want that.

Thanks.

Comment: Would not `br:hidden` be enough? http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could try:

```
$("br").filter(function() { return $(this).css("display") == "none" })
```

Answer (score 15):

Another way to do this would be to use jQuery's attribute selector:

```
$("br[style$='display: none;']")
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [filter](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/filter).

```
$("br").filter(function () {
    return $(this).css("display") == "none";
});
```

Comment: Not sure why this is getting upvoted since it will not work!  It needs to be the CSS attribute and not an attribute on the HTML element

Comment: It should be `css()` instead of `attr()`. `display` is CSS not HTML attribute

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div:hidden").each(function() {
    if ($(this).css("display") == "none") {
        // do something
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.map:

```
var brs = $('br');
jQuery.map(brs, function(elem, i){
    if(elem.css('display') == 'none')
        return elem;
    return null;
});
```

Comment: Actually filter's probably better.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("br").filter(function() {
  return $(this).css("display") == "none";
})
```

Works like a charm.