# Is there a way to find all elements matching a certain style using the DOM(Using jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you select elements based on their style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442048/how-do-you-select-elements-based-on-their-style)
>   [jquery select all br with display:none;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616006/jquery-select-all-br-with-displaynone)

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <li style="display:none">i am not visible</li>
    <li>i am visible</li>
    <li>i am visibile</li>
  </ul>
  <div style="display:none">i am not visible</li>
</body>
```

I want to select all the elements which  display is none.For example in the code above,i want to select the li and the div which html is 'i am not visible'.is there any way to do this using jQuery the best or someway else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442048/how-do-you-select-elements-based-on-their-style might help `:)`

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
$(document.body).find(':not(:visible)')
```

or better :

```
$('li,div').not(':visible')
```

Beware not to be too wide in your selectors : you would get many not wanted elements.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/kqfgj/) (open the console)

---

Note that it's generally preferable to use a class :

CSS :

```
.notVisible {display:none;}
```

HTML :

```
 <li class=notVisible>i am not visible</li>
```

JQuery :

```
$('.notVisible')
```

Comment: @karaxuna: I would assume that the `$('*')` selector is going to be the last choice as it is the widest selector and goes through all the DOM elements which is the most inefficient way. One should be as specific as possible with the selectors. This is not micro-optimisation but the difference in performance could be quite noticeable on large pages.

Comment: @dystroy: +1 for nice DEMO and good explanation.

Comment: @dystroy I agree about performance, but your answer was wrong, it was searching only 'li' invisible tags, now its better :) +1

Answer (score 0):

```
$('*').css('display') == 'none'
```

you can use this in the if condition followed by your requirements

Hope this helps:D

Comment: since you want all the elements that are having display : none