# jquery stop .each() method for child level

Tags: jquery, html, cookies, each

I'm working on a multilevel menu state saving function that would save opened menuitems in a cookie.

It working but I have an issue.. When the each method loops through the list it saves every childnode event the parent is visible or not.

Here's a [fiddle][http://jsfiddle.net/gtV8E/] to see the code in work..
My aim is that save only the visible menu items's indexes.

Comment: I don't see the problem.  Did you fix it already?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add class to invisible (or visible) elements and save only childnodes without/or with certain class for example.

Or filter elements that haven't  display none css value [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616006/jquery-select-all-br-with-displaynone).